# Shell won't start after change from zsh to bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, elementary-os

I was using `zsh` for a couple of years on my ElementaryOS. I started to play with some settings yesterday and I wanted to switch to bash temporarily with `chsh -s bash`. Then I restarted the terminal and the window is now completely empty (nothing gets loaded and no error message is displayed). However, it's possible I made a typo or did something wrong, I don't really remember and it's not saved in the `hist` file.

So is there a way how to fix this without going to GRUP, mounting a disk and play with shell settings there? I am running ElementaryOS Loki based on Ubuntu 16.10 [image]

Comment: Does the same happen why you try to log in in TTY?

Comment: Doesn't `chsh` expect a complete absolute path to the new shell, and doesn't it complain if the shell given on the command line is not actually listed in `/etc/shells`?  You can probably make your terminal start a shell of your choice through its configuration settings. Set that to `zsh` (preferably the full path). Then start a new terminal. In that new terminal, run `bash` to see whether that works at all.  You don't change your login shell _temporarily_ with `chsh`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I managed to change shell via dconf Editor so I'll accept your answer if you write with :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @PetrMensik Since I don't know exactly what you did, or if you managed to change your shell to `bash` as you initially intended, I don't feel like I can write a detailed answer. It would be better if you wrote an answer yourself (which is  a perfectly reasonable thing to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my shell path with dconf editor available Ubuntu/elementaryOS [image]